# Save Python Variable values to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

As per the heading of my question, What I have si a variable which contains 
an array of values like

```
1
4
3
5
3
5
3
5
4
5
3
6
4
6
```

the values are stored in a variable name `datawindow4`
Now what I want is that I want to save these values in a CSV format. so that I can use it for further purpose. 
How can I pursue that? is there any way?
Please suggest. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: post the final csv content with concrete field separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your variable is a 1d list containing numbers:

```
import csv
datawindow4 = [1,2,3,4]
with open('new.csv', 'w') as f:
    for d in datawindow4:
        f.write(str(d))
        f.write("\n")
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is just a text file with a delimiter to separate value.

You can simply open a file, iterate your value and puts them into your file, close your file

or use the library csv : [here the question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465447/writing-array-to-csv-python-one-column)

Comment: its throwing an error  ```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open("your_csv.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in your_array:
            writer.writerow(line)
```